# Automatic user logout on 401 axios interceptor

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have been trying long to implement react automatic logout as soon the JWT token expires after 1 hour.
I am new to using axios interceptor in react. I searched a lot to understand interceptor use case in react API requests but is unable to implement it completely.

Here is the intercept approach I tried to follow:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import LocalData from '../localstorage';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';


const getToken = LocalData.getLocalData('currentUser', 'getToken');


function ReqResInterceptor(){


    // Add a request interceptor
    const reqIntercept = axios.interceptors.request.use(
        config => {
            const token = getToken;
            if(token){
                config.headers['x-access-token'] = token;
                config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
            }
            return config;        
        },
        (error) => {
            Promise.reject(error);
        }
    );


    //Add a response interceptor
    const resIntercept = axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
        return response
    }, () => {
        if(error.response.status === 401){
            LocalData.removeLocalData();
            <Redirect to="/login" />
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    })

}

export default ReqResInterceptor;
```

Here is my component that scopes under protected route:

```
class DefaultLayout extends Component {

  loading = () => <div className="animated fadeIn pt-1 text-center">Loading...</div>


  componentDidMount(){
    let userInfo = LocalData.getLocalData('currentUser', 'all');
    console.log(userInfo);

    if (userInfo.success === false && userInfo.responseStatus === 401){
      LocalData.removeLocalData();
      return <Redirect to="/login"/>
    }
  }


  signOut(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();
    LocalData.removeLocalData();
    this.props.history.push('/login')
  }

  render() {
    //console.log(this.props)
    return ( ....
}
```

And my `App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.scss';
import ProtectedRoute from './containers/AuthContext/ProtectedRoute';
import ReqResInterceptor from './containers/helpers/AxiosInterceptor/AxiosInterceptor';


const loading = () => <div className="animated fadeIn pt-3 text-center loader"></div>;

// Containers
const DefaultLayout = React.lazy(() => import('./containers/DefaultLayout'));

// Pages
const Login = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Pages/Login'));
const Register = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Pages/Register'));

class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (

        <BrowserRouter>
          <React.Suspense fallback={loading()}>
            <Switch>
              <ReqResInterceptor />
                  <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                  <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
                  <Route path="/" component={ProtectedRoute(DefaultLayout)} />
            </Switch>
          </React.Suspense>
        </BrowserRouter>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am confused on using interceptor to achieve automatic redirection. Please help to figure this out.

Comment: Can you clarify where the api calls are being made using axios? An interceptor needs to be attached to an Axios instance to effectively intercept requests and responses.

Comment: @Leander I have login component that makes axios call and then stores the token to local storage. I need to implement automatic  logout functionality in 'DefaultLayout' component. The 'DefaultLayout' is a protected route which is accessible only after the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

An axios interceptor needs to be attached to the instance that is making the requests. It seems you are trying to add the interceptor as a jsx component inside your dom-tree, which is probably not going to work.

To make it work, add the interceptor to the axios instance before making the calls.

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create();
// Add your interceptors here
instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {});
instance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {});

export default instance;
```

Now you can re-use the axios instance with the added interceptors.

Comment: please help me clear one more doubt. The approach I am following to call interceptor inside my protected route i.e. DefaultLayout, is this correct to do so to implement automatic logout?

Comment: No, an interceptor is not a function you can call in other components. It needs to be tightly connected to the axios instance that is making the calls. On it's own, an interceptor is useless.

Comment: Then how can I implement automatic logout ? I thought of implementing interceptor for the same, but now it seems useless. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well one possible way I can think of is managing the authentication state within your highest component, in this case your ```App``` component. If you implement a check there to verify if a token is still valid, you can act accordingly and deny or grant access to a protected route.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate !